# How can i deploy a Next.js app with Mongodb to heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I've been trying to deploy my Next.js application with mongoDb to heroku platform with no luck. it builds successfully without any errors but for some reasons my app does not work. I checked my heroku logs, and i found this error message.

```
2020-08-17T21:09:10.846691+00:00 app[web.1]: FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/notes/favicon.ico failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

The homepage gets displayed and i can navigate to different routes. but the data that is supposed to be coming from mongoDb is not being displayed. i cannot perform any CRUD operation. I get a **500 internal server error** on the homepage and also in the console.

I researched a lot about this issue but i haven't been able to come up with a solution. Here's where i'm making a connection to my mongoDb. i have also added my config Vars in the heroku GUI.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const connection = {}

const dbConnect = async () => {
if (connection.isConnected) {
  return
} 
 const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
   dbName: process.env.DB_NAME,
   user: process.env.DB_USER,
   pass: process.env.DB_PASS,
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
 })

 connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState
 console.log(connection.isConnected, 'Db connected')
}

export default dbConnect
```

Please what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ur updating ur connection link to the mongodb URL and not the mongodb on your localhost... Update the MONGO_URI variable in your .env file with the link to ur mongodb url